# Changing properties from one entity to another in coredata modelling tool

Tags: xcode, core-data

In apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH4-SW1) it says like this regarding the lightweight migration:

> Changing the entity hierarchy
>
> You can add, remove, rename entities
>
> **You can create a new parent or child entity and move properties up and down the entity hierarchy**
>
> You can move entities out of a hierarchy
>
> You cannot, however, merge entity hierarchies; if two existing entities do not share a common parent in the source, they cannot share a common parent in the destination

How can move a property from one entity to another using the Xcode's modelling tool?

Comment: I dont really get your question. What do you want to do with the property? Add it to another entity or get a relation to an entity?

Comment: I want to "move" the property from the parent to the child entity. As the docs say it is possible